# call a contact programmatically

Tags: ios, call, contacts

I want to get contacts information and make a call to their phoneNumber programmatically, I have searched a lot but I couldn't find objective-C code to access contacts and make the call. I'm using the following code for calling:

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://PhoneNumber"]];
```

Please let me know how I can call a contact programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

The URL scheme you need is `tel:`

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://PhoneNumber"]];
```

Comment: Thanks, The URL scheme telPrompt is also working, but I'm asking how I can access contact information?

Comment: @Niloufar in that case check out the Contacts.framework (iOS 9 only) https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328 If you want iOS <=8 then use the AddressBook.framework from the dupe link